# Postgres+Hibernate+NativeQuery: Joda DateTime to Postgres TIMSTAMP

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Model

```
package domain;
@Entity @lombok.Getter @lombok.Setter
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP", updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Type(type= "PersistentDateTime") // typedef in package-info.java
    private DateTime createdAt; // Joda's DateTime
}
```

Repository

```
package repository;
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, UUID> {

    // Has to be native query
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE created_at >= :created_at ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Event> findCreatedSince(@Param(value = "created_at") DateTime createdAt);

}
```

When I call `findCreatedSince(someDateTime)` it throws `PSQLException` with message `"cannot cast type bytea to timestamp without time zone"`. (The thing is when it's normal JPQL, there's no complain. In fact data can be stored and retrieved perfectly using standard JPA repository methods).
For the record I got the following log (note `VARBINARY`) when calling the method:

`[main] TRACE BasicBinder – binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00]`

For temporary resolution I change the type of `createdAt` to `java.util.Date`, but I'd like to know how I can use Joda's `DateTime` type. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe your JPA providers doesn't support Jodatime types out of the box? The JPA provider I use (DataNucleus) does, but Jodatime types are not covered by the JPA spec.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, since normal JPQL calls work just fine I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: If something is mapping a column as "bytea" then no it doesn't work. Hibernate generated your schema? and it put the Jodatime field as "bytea" ? i.e serialised.

Answer (score 0):

In Repository, change DateTime to Date:

```
List<Event> findCreatedSince(@Param(value = "created_at") Date createdAt);
```

When you use:

```
...findCreatedSince(Date.valueOf(createdAt))
```